Flooring type and install
In the process of selecting flooring for my family room -> hallway ->entryway.
Current flooring is carpet and Pergo over concrete.
I want to install the same flooring [LVP?] in these three areas and my cracked head idea is to install the planks at a 45 to the walls.
Thoughts on the 45 to the wall and any recommendations for flooring.
Family room is 14'x24'
Thanks

LVP and similar type flooring wants a decently flat flooring.  The instructions should have an amount of maximum height change per foot.  This is not about a flat slope which is good but dips/ridges.  Carpet might hide this.

LVP is a great choice for your space—it's durable and stylish. Installing it at a 45-degree angle will definitely make your rooms look unique and dynamic. Just remember, you'll need more materials because of the extra cuts.
I did something similar in my home, and while I had to buy extra planks, the end result was amazing. The diagonal layout really made the space feel bigger. Good luck with your project!
I have seen a few websites that have great flooring:
https://furnishmyplace.com/flooring/lvp/
https://www.flooringamerica.com/flooring
https://www.flooringusa.net/

Installing LVP at a 45-degree angle can create a striking, unique look and make the space feel more dynamic, especially in large areas like your 14'x24' family room. However, it may increase material waste and labor costs. For durability, choose a high-quality, waterproof LVP with a strong wear layer for high-traffic areas like hallways and entryways.
